# Why does the first firebase call for real time database take too much time after first response it works much faster

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, ios11

I am using firebase real-time database in my application, but I am facing one weird issue. The first firebase call takes too much time after first response the works much faster.

```
 Database.database().reference().child(FireBaseTable.bpmTable).child(firebaseKey).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print("Initial load done2")
            })
```

After first response, same code with diff/same key gives much faster response.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to index data in your rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
}
```

**Index can be set like this:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinosaurs": {
      ".indexOn": ["height", "length"]
    }
  }
}
```

> "Firebase allows you to do ad-hoc queries on your data using an
>   arbitrary child key. If you know in advance what your indexes will be,
>   you can define them via the .indexOn rule in your Firebase Realtime
>   Database Rules to improve query performance."